# substract current date with another date in dataframe scala

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark, timestamp, unix-timestamp

First of all, thank you for the time in reading my question :)

My question is the following: In Spark with Scala, i have a dataframe that there contains a string with a date in format dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm, for example df

```
+----------------+
|date            |
+----------------+
|8/11/2017 15:00 |
|9/11/2017 10:00 |
+----------------+
```

i want to get the difference of currentDate with date of dataframe in second, for example

df.withColumn("difference", currentDate - unix_timestamp(col(date)))

```
+----------------+------------+
|date            | difference |
+----------------+------------+
|8/11/2017 15:00 | xxxxxxxxxx |
|9/11/2017 10:00 | xxxxxxxxxx |
+----------------+------------+
```

I try

```
val current = current_timestamp()
df.withColumn("difference", current - unix_timestamp(col(date)))
```

but get this error

> > org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(current_timestamp() - unix_timestamp(`date`, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))' due to data type mismatch: differing types in '(current_timestamp() - unix_timestamp(`date`, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))' (timestamp and bigint).;;

I try too

```
val current = BigInt(System.currenttimeMillis / 1000)
df.withColumn("difference", current - unix_timestamp(col(date)))
```

and

```
val current = unix_timestamp(current_timestamp())
but the col "difference" is null
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use correct format for `unix_timestamp`:

```
df.withColumn("difference", current_timestamp().cast("long") - unix_timestamp(col("date"), "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm"))
```

or with recent version:

```
to_timestamp(col("date"), "dd/mm/yyyy HH:mm") - current_timestamp())
```

to get `Interval` column.